# A character counter in js?

Tags: javascript, count, character

So I am currently programming my very first website. I am using pure javascript. A part of it will be a comments section - which are stored in a SQL- Database on the server. I want comments to have a maximum length. After searching the web I found this solution. Please do note that this solution is far from perfect.

```js
var maxchar = 160;
var i = document.getElementById("textinput");
var c = document.getElementById("count");
c.innerHTML = maxchar;

i.addEventListener("keydown", count);

function count(e) {
  var len = i.value.length;
  if (len >= maxchar) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    c.innerHTML = maxchar - len - 1;
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
Remaining characters: <span id="count"></span>
<textarea id="textinput">
</textarea>
```

I found a lot of similar solutions also using jQuery. Now this solution has two major flaws. First it counts the characters before the new character is entered since the registered event is the keydown event - value.length will always give the old count. Secondly once you hit the maximum amount of characters it will prevent all user input - there is no way to delete characters anymore.

Registering the count to keyup doesn't help either - it can't prevent the input of the keydown event.

What is a better solution than this?

Comment: I believe it is better to simply display a warning that the content is too long and then disable the submit button until the issue is resolved... handle it like you would any other validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around with it for a bit I came up with this solution. The trick is to split up the count function into two parts - one which counts the characters and one which prevents the user input. Register the preventInput() on keydown, such that the input is prevented before entering, and register the count() on keyup, such that the new value of length is used in the function.

```js
function preventInput(event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'commentText')
    var maxchar = 255;
  else
    var maxchar = 20;
  //I'm using target here, such that I can use this as a callback for different textfields
  var len = event.target.value.length;
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  //prevent every input apart from UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT and BACKSPACE
  if (len >= maxchar && (key != 8 && !(key >= 37 && key <= 40)))
    event.preventDefault();
}

function count(event) {
  //different lengths for different textfields
  if (event.target.id == 'commentText')
    var maxchar = 255;
  else
    var maxchar = 20;
  var len = event.target.value.length;
  //setting the remaining chars field depending whether Author or Text triggered the event
  document.getElementById("remain" + event.target.id.split('comment')[1]).innerHTML = 'Remaining characters:' + (maxchar - len);
  //disable the submit button when the user entered too many chars (CTRL + V)
  var btn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
  if (len > maxchar)
    btn.disabled = true;
  else
    btn.disabled = false;
}

function setup() {
  //setting to events
  document.getElementById("commentAuthor").addEventListener("keydown", preventInput);
  document.getElementById("commentAuthor").addEventListener("keyup", count);
  document.getElementById("commentText").addEventListener("keydown", preventInput);
  document.getElementById("commentText").addEventListener("keyup", count);
  //initial count
  document.getElementById("remainAuthor").innerHTML += 20;
  document.getElementById("remainText").innerHTML += 255;
}
```

```css
.charCounter {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setup()">
  <form>
    <fieldset style="display: inline-block;">
      <legend>Submit a comment</legend>
      Name:
      <input type="text" id="commentAuthor" name="Name:">
      <div class="charCounter" id="remainAuthor">Remaining characters:</div>
      <textarea name="comment" id="commentText" rows="4" cols="100"></textarea>
      <div class="charCounter" id="remainText">Remaining characters:</div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit Comment!">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the first snipped into something like this

```js
var maxchar = 160;
var i = document.getElementById("commentText");
var c = document.getElementById("remainText");
c.innerHTML = maxchar;

i.addEventListener("keydown", count);

function count(e) {
  var len = i.value.length;
  len >= maxchar ? i.value = i.value.slice(0,len-1) : c.innerHTML = maxchar - len - 1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setup()">
  <form>
    <fieldset style="display: inline-block;">
      <legend>Submit a comment</legend>
      Name:
      <input type="text" id="commentAuthor" name="Name:">
      <div class="charCounter" id="remainAuthor">Remaining characters:</div>
      <textarea name="comment" id="commentText" rows="4" cols="100"></textarea>
      <div class="charCounter" id="remainText">Remaining characters:</div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit Comment!">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```